# Joining 3 tables in MySQL (3 deep)

Tags: mysql

I've got three tables as described below that I need to query.  I understand simple JOINs, but this one is a little beyond my level.

`courses` has two columns `id (PK)`, and `courseTitle` (example id 1, courseTitle Physics)

`classes` has three columns.  `id (PK), courseID, startDate`  (courseID refers to the id column in table courses).

`evals` has lots of columns.  `id (PK), classID, instructorID, .....`

As an end result, I would like my SELECT query to end up with:
all of the `evals` columns, plus `course.courseTitle` (based on classes.courseID), and `classes.startDate`

I'm pretty sure I could do this in two steps, but I want to do it the "right" way.

Comment: Please add your query to show your effort

Comment: where is your database..??
table name with column(s)...??
We need info to solve your problems...:)

Answer (score 0):

The same logic in joining two tables applies also when joining three- just join them twice with the primary id columns

```
select evals.*,  courses.courseTitle, classes.startDate from
evals inner join classes on evals.classId = classes.id
Inner join courses on classes.courseId = courses.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` all three tables together using their relations (primary key/foreign key).

Showing one or more colums can be achieved by specifying the `TABLENAME.FIELDNAME`.
Showing all the columns in one table you need to specify the `TABLENAME.*`

```
SELECT
    course.courseTitle,
    classes.startDate,
    evals.*
FROM
    course
JOIN 
    classes on course.id = classes.courseID
JOIN 
    evals on evals.classID = classes.id
```